# How to package example scripts using distribute?

Tags: python, packaging, distribute

I use *distribute* to package a small python library. I made a directory structure as described in [the Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html).

My question: Where (in the directory structure) do I place example scripts that show how to use the library and what changes are necessary to the `setup.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its good, not to install the examples,
rather you can keep your `examples` folder with your distribution, so it may be on the same level where your setup.py,

If you want to include them, then include as separate module of package, like 'example' - and that directory holds the all example scripts, that users can refer even after installing.

```
package_data = {
        'module_1': [files],
        'module_2': [files],
        'example': [files],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example scripts are a type of documentation, so install them in the same way you would install other documentation: [as package_data](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data).